# Low latency R submits

Tags: r

I have created some R codes, which accept a csv and produces and output, now I call these by:

```
Rscript code.R input.csv
```

Here code.R is the the code to be executed and input.csv is the file which it uses as input

**Problem:**

The script takes 5 seconds or more to produce results, that is because R is called from shell, the libraries need time to be loaded.

**Question:**

Is it possible to run R in background or as a service with all libraries loaded that I can just do submit my job and it just takes time to compute?

**Full disclosure:**

The script is a ML model which loads an .RDA object and the scripts calls predict function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open your R console and run/load all the libraries that are required.
2. Use `source()` to now run your R scripts

Test.R file has the following code

```
#This file has no library declarations
c <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl)))
c <- c + geom_bar()
print(c)
```

Now I run from my console like this

```
> library(ggplot2)
> source("<Path>/test.R")
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Edit: To pass Params along with source() command**

You can do this by overriding `commandArgs()`

New test.R file code:

```
c <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl)))
c <- c + geom_bar()
print(c)
print(commandArgs())
```

Now from console:

```
> commandArgs <- function() c('a','b')
> source("<Path>/test.R")
[1] "a" "b"
(Along with the graph)
```

Comment: I want a method to that can be automated. this requires opening console, i doubt i can pass parameters to this!, if you can then i am interested